# Sitecore 8.2 unlock item / unlock all items error

Tags: sitecore-client

We're facing an issue on the Unlock all functionality.

PS: The unlock only works after Saving the item (Once we have activated the unlock after saving property).

If we click on the unlock button, the item disappears but returns after refresh, so, it doesn't unlock at all.

When clicking on "unlock all button", it shows the message error below:

**An error occured**

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Stack is null or empty. at Sitecore.Common.Switcher2.Exit() at
>
> Sitecore.Common.Switcher2.Dispose() at
>   Sitecore.Data.Locking.ItemLocking.Unlock() at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.UnlockAll.UnlockAllItems(Object[]
>   parameters) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method,
>   Object[] parameters, Object obj) at
>   Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args) at (Object , Object[]
>   ) at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) at
>   Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Sitecore version: Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 161115)

[image: Error 1 - Unlock page]

[image: Error 2 - First Error Page]

[image: Error 3 - Detail message]

Comment: Have you checked the Sitecore logs. There may be some useful information around the same time as the error. Additionally, try rebuilding the master index.

Comment: Also you should check if is there any custom processor breaking this functionality. Try disabling them and see if it works.

Comment: try using the admin user to unlock the items

Comment: For me it was another issue but similar. I got the System.Reflection.TargetInovationException too but with itemOnSave() method, and it turns out that I had a bug in one of my custom pipelines that implements OnItemSave method. Therefore, maybe check if there is any custom pipelines/methods that implements the UnlockAllItems() method?

Comment: Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange :-)   Your input is very much appreciated. This here is more of a comment though, than an actual attempt to answer. I will convert it to a comment for you. Once you've been with us for a while, your account will gain the ability to post comments directly.